# Check for nil in NSUserDefault String

Tags: xcode, nsuserdefaults, null

I know this seems like it should be so simple...

I'm extracting a string value from my NSUserDefaults:

```
 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *strFirstName = [userDefaults stringForKey:kFirstPersonName];
```

This gives me the "comparison between pointer and integer" error:

```
 if (!strFirstName == nil) {    
      self.firstPersonName.text = strFirstName;
 }
```

What I'm trying to do is extract a value from the user defaults. If it's nil, don't use it. If it has a string value, use it.

Any help is appreciated!
lq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

!strFirstName treats the variable strFirstName as an integer. Instead, you want to type `if ( strFirstName != nil ) ...`

Comment: Marc, Thank you very much! It's been a long day of coding... I should shoot myself before asking that type of question.